# Give column name when read csv file pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is the example of my dataset.

```
>>> user1 = pd.read_csv('dataset/1.csv')
>>> print(user1)
          0  0.69464   3.1735   7.5048
0  0.030639  0.14982  3.48680   9.2755
1  0.069763 -0.29965  1.94770   9.1120
2  0.099823 -1.68890  1.41650  10.1200
3  0.129820 -2.17930  0.95342  10.9240
4  0.159790 -2.30180  0.23155  10.6510
5  0.189820 -1.41650  1.18500  11.0730
```

How to push down the first column and add the names column [TIME, X, Y, and Z] on the first column.

The desired output is like this:

```
       TIME        X        Y        Z
0         0  0.69464   3.1735   7.5048
1  0.030639  0.14982  3.48680   9.2755
2  0.069763 -0.29965  1.94770   9.1120
3  0.099823 -1.68890  1.41650  10.1200
4  0.129820 -2.17930  0.95342  10.9240
5  0.159790 -2.30180  0.23155  10.6510
6  0.189820 -1.41650  1.18500  11.0730
```

Answer (score 249, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
colnames=['TIME', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'] 
user1 = pd.read_csv('dataset/1.csv', names=colnames, header=None)
```

Comment: Is `header=None` necessary since we provide the column names?

Comment: If the column names are supplied, the parameter `header` is not required. As per the documentation: "if column names are passed explicitly then the behavior is identical to `header=None`". See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Can I exclude some of those columns directly?

Comment: header=None produces oodles of error statements. Panda 1.5.3, Python 3.11.4, MacOS Monterey

Answer (score 28):

we can do it with a single line of code.

```
 user1 = pd.read_csv('dataset/1.csv', names=['TIME', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], header=None)
```

Answer (score 13):

If we are directly use data from csv it will give combine data based on comma separation value as it is .csv file.

```
user1 = pd.read_csv('dataset/1.csv')
```

If you want to add column names using pandas, you have to do something like this. But below code will not show separate header for your columns.

```
col_names=['TIME', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'] 
user1 = pd.read_csv('dataset/1.csv', names=col_names)
```

To solve above problem we have to add extra filled which is supported by pandas, It is **header=None**

```
user1 = pd.read_csv('dataset/1.csv', names=col_names, header=None)
```

Answer (score 12):

In addition to above answers if your dataset already has column names and you want to replace it with your custom names then set `header=0` instead of `header=None`

Comment: To get them: columns = chunk.columns.tolist()

Comment: this is so useful I feel like it should at least be mentioned in the answer, even though it's not what the OP asked for

Answer (score 8):

```
user1  = pd.read_csv('dataset/1.csv',  names=['Time',  'X',  'Y',  'Z'])
```

names parameter in read_csv function is used to define  column names. If you pass extra name in this list,  it will add another new column with that name with NaN values.

header=None is used to trim column names is already exists in CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nrows=1` to avoid consuming loading time if the dataset is too large.