# How to read .data format data with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have uploaded data from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/arrhythmia/ . As you see it has .data format. How to read it as pandas datframe in Python?

I try this. but it dens work:

```
with open("arrhythmia.data", "r") as f:
    arryth_df = pd.DataFrame(f.read())
```

It says ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: @jezrael yeah, yours is right. thought column names part is still unclear

Comment: I check `arrhythmia.names` but here is only description, It seems some values should be changed by rename `df =df.rename(columns=0:'col1', 1:'col2')`

Comment: If possible create list of all names of columns like `names= ['col1','col2','col3',...]` is possible use `df = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, names=names)`

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31645466) Q/A, only my list is called `names`, so assigned instead `names=colnames` here `names=names`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `url` of file to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) because here `.data` is csv format, but no header, so added `header=None`:

```
#if want see all data
pd.options.display.max_columns = None

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/arrhythmia/arrhythmia.data'
df = pd.read_csv(url, header=None)
print (df.head())

  0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11  12  13  14   15   \
0   75    0  190   80   91  193  371  174  121  -16  13   64  -2   ?  63    0   
1   56    1  165   64   81  174  401  149   39   25  37  -17  31   ?  53    0   
2   54    0  172   95  138  163  386  185  102   96  34   70  66  23  75    0   
3   55    0  175   94  100  202  380  179  143   28  11   -5  20   ?  71    0   
4   75    0  190   80   88  181  360  177  103  -16  13   61   3   ?   ?    0   

   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   \
0   52   44    0    0   32    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   44   20   36   
1   48    0    0    0   24    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   64    0    0   
2   40   80    0    0   24    0    0    0    0    0    0   20   56   52    0   
3   72   20    0    0   48    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   64   36    0   
4   48   40    0    0   28    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   40   24    0   
...
...
...
```

If want also convert `?` to missing values `NaN`s add `na_values='?'` parameter:

```
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/arrhythmia/arrhythmia.data'
df = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, na_values='?')
print (df.head())

   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9     10    11    12    13   \
0   75    0  190   80   91  193  371  174  121  -16  13.0  64.0  -2.0   NaN   
1   56    1  165   64   81  174  401  149   39   25  37.0 -17.0  31.0   NaN   
2   54    0  172   95  138  163  386  185  102   96  34.0  70.0  66.0  23.0   
3   55    0  175   94  100  202  380  179  143   28  11.0  -5.0  20.0   NaN   
4   75    0  190   80   88  181  360  177  103  -16  13.0  61.0   3.0   NaN   

    14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   \
0  63.0    0   52   44    0    0   32    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   44   
1  53.0    0   48    0    0    0   24    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   64   
2  75.0    0   40   80    0    0   24    0    0    0    0    0    0   20   56   
3  71.0    0   72   20    0    0   48    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   64   
4   NaN    0   48   40    0    0   28    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   40  
...
...
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Here is a complement that I was about to write in my answer. "A `.data` could be any format. The file extension does not dictate the format of the file. I opened the file in notepad and noticed that the values in it are comma-separated. There is a built-in reader function in pandas that takes care of loading comma-separated files, pd.read_csv"

Comment: and there is no column names? i think they are in arrhythmia.names. is it possible to add them as column names?

Comment: @french_fries - Is possible defined columns names by list?

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way with `StringIO`:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
with open("arrhythmia.data", "r") as f:
    data = StringIO(f.read())
    arryth_df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Comment: and there is no column names? i think they are in arrhythmia.names. is it possible to add them as column names?