# PANDAS: How to rename a column but not lose its previous text in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

Okay so I was reading up a text file and using `.read_csv()` and ended up with this dataframe:

[image: Image DF]

But the problem is that, the `im feeling rather rotten...` text is ended up being as a column rather than a dataframe feature, and when I try to rename the column I just end up losing the feature all together, and skipping onto the 2nd value in the dataframe:
[image]

**EDIT:**
This is how I read in the text file.
[image]

Any answers, comments are heartfully accepted.

Comment: use `pd.read_csv("emotions.txt", sep=";", header=None)` since you dont have a header

Comment: Can you please share the first two lines of your file in the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Give column name when read csv file pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645466/give-column-name-when-read-csv-file-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution would be (respectfully concluded by @luigigi)
`pd.read_csv("emotions.txt", sep=";", header=None)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-defined the columns name with the code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('emotions.txt', sep =';', names=['TEXT','EMOTION'], header=None)
```